# pseudocolors in R

Tags: r, image-processing

I'd like to take this kind of 16-bit TIFF image as input:

[image: original image]

then turn the grayscale into rainbow pseudocolors like this:

[image: false color image]

and add a color key before exporting the resulting image again as TIFF image.

Is there a way to turn a grayscale image to a pseudocolor image in R?

Comment: If you don't know how to transpose a matrix, then I strongly suggest you start by reading the introductory tutorials on `R` . Then read the help files on every function you come across so you understand what arguments are available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out the following solution for this problem (using the following image http://www.biomedimaging.org/BookImages/GeneExpressionCy3.tif as an example). The following code reads the grayscale `TIFF` image, rotates it 90° counterclockwise and uses a colour palette to generate an image with pseudocolors.

```
library(tiff)
library(RColorBrewer)

img <- readTIFF("example.tif")

colnum <- 256

cols <- ceiling(img[,,1] * (colnum - 1) + 1)
# If img consists of a 2D-array: cols <- ceiling(img * (colnum - 1) + 1).
# Use cols <- ceiling(t(img[,,1] * (colnum - 1) + 1)) if you don't want to
# rotate the image.

#pal <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "skyblue", "yellow", "red", "darkred"),
#   bias = 1)(colnum) as suggested by @lukeA
pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrBr"), space = 'rgb')(colnum)

# Create lookup-table to match the palette colours with the numeric values
lut <- data.frame(col = 1:colnum, pal, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
cols2 <- lut[match(cols, lut[,1]),2]
dim(cols2) <- dim(cols)

img.width <- dim(cols)[1]
img.height <- dim(cols)[2]

tiff("example_coloured.tiff", width = img.width, height = img.height,
  units = "px", res = 300)
layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1), widths = c(4,1), heights = c(4,4))
layout.show(2)

par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
image(matrix(1:(img.height * img.width), ncol = img.height, nrow = img.width),
  col = cols2, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", frame.plot = FALSE)

par(mar = c(0,0.1,0,0))
image(t(matrix(1:img.width, ncol = 1, nrow = img.width)), 
  col = pal, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", frame.plot = FALSE)

dev.off()
```

**The only thing I'm still missing is how to add some text (e.g. -high / -low at the ends) to the colour key.** I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you take gif as input:

```
library(caTools)
y <- read.gif("the.gif")   

# create color palette based on brightness of colors (bright = red, dark = blue)
brightness <- colSums(col2rgb(y$col))                                            
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "skyblue", "yellow", "red", "darkred"),    
                        bias=1)(max(brightness)+1)

# prepare export
tiff("the.tiff", compression = "lzw")                                      
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=rep(1,4))                                                  

# plot original image
image(y$image, col=y$col,                                     
      xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", asp = 1)
# plot rotated image with new pal below
image(apply(y$image, 1, rev), col=pal[brightness+1],                             
      xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", asp = 1)

# create dummy legend with reduced 5 color palette
clusters <- kmeans(t(col2rgb(pal[brightness+1])),   
                   centers = k <- 5)
legend(x="right", fill=rgb(clusters$centers/255), 
       legend=replicate(k, 
                        paste(letters[sample(1:10, 5)], 
                              collapse="")))
# export to tiff
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This works perfectly with `GIF`files, thanks! However, I haven't managed to transfer your approach to `TIFF` images yet. I can read (and rotate) the `TIFF` image with `readTIFF`from `tiff` or `readImage` from `EBImage` packages, but the structure of the image I've imported is completely different from that of an imported `GIF`: the image is simply a 3D numeric array. Another thing is that I'd prefer to have a continuous colour key, but that would be the next step. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your work!

Comment: @AnjaM You are welcome. The easiest may be to convert tif to gif. E.g. by batch processing using a common image viewer (FastStone, ..). Or by using a temporary file ... something in the veins of `y <- readTIFF("my.tif"); write.gif(image=y, filename=tmp <- tempfile(fileext=".gif")); y <- read.gif(tmp); y$image <- y$image[,,1]`.